# Benchmark Join and Sudoku

Tags: hadoop, join, mapreduce, sudoku

I am new to Hadoop.  I want to run join benchmark. How can i get data set for input ? can you please give an example for running it ?

One more thing, I want to solve Sudoku problem  as given on the link
http://magictour.free.fr/top95. I have replaced '.' by '  ?  ' in the dataset before running it on Hadoop. But i am getting following error==>

```
Solving /root/exp_testing/mysrc/spsa_wordoccurrence/dataset/pjava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 159568
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.dancing.Sudoku.generateRow(Sudoku.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.dancing.Sudoku.makeModel(Sudoku.java:293)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.dancing.Sudoku.solve(Sudoku.java:301)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.dancing.Sudoku.main(Sudoku.java:317)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that last line has junk character. I think that is the issue. Check that if you still face issue, update your input file.

Comment: ok thanks, can u please do some help on running join benchmark ?

Comment: search (join: A job that effects a join over sorted, equally partitioned datasets).                                                                                            reference - http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/